# Getting the top occurrence in Excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that has columns "Date", "Name", "Email" and "Version" each user has a version. but it is repeating with previous and new versions. I want to see what is the latest version of the user, neglecting all the previous version the user had. Like Dawid has 01.3.37 now, so I don't need previous rows, Igor has his last version 01.3.35. so I don't need his previous row

[image]

the output should look like this with removed repeating emails but with latest versions only

[image]

Comment: Please, add example data easy to copy/paste using [markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, edit your question and add expected output. About dates, are real dates or text dates?

Comment: Will your version scheme always be in that exact format?  `nn.nn.nn` ?  Or might there be letters, 1 or 3 digit numbers, etc.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld 01.03 are constant 37 can change but it always is two digits

Comment: Then please check out the solution proposed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, B2:B8, FILTER(A2:D8,MAXIFS(A2:A8,α,α)=A2:A8))
```

---

Comment: what is 'a' in your formula?

Comment: It is not `a` it is `alpha` --> `α` a variable to store the repeating range: `B2:B8`

Comment: @Tim is it not working for you? also let me know what specific issues or problems arising